# Function JQUERY with anchor in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, window, anchor, href, pure-js

How would get this to work with pure js?

```html
<form id="formBuscaAncoraHash" class="search-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="icon fa fa-search"></span>
        <input id="buscaRaca" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="submit" value="Digite um nome" />
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
var anchor = $("#buscaRaca").val();
var position = $("#"+anchor).offset();
window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top);
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. And/or [study this](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var archon = document.getElementById('buscaRaca').value;
var position = document.getElementById(archon).getBoundingClientRect();
```